# Find the flaw in this math code

Tags: math-mode

I simply can't find the flaw in this code:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
x_0'^2-x_1'^2 & = {(x_0 - \beta x_1)}^2 \gamma^2 - {(x_1 - \beta x_0)}^2 
\gamma^2  \\
& = \frac{ (x_0^2 - 2 \beta x_1 x_0 + \beta^2 x_1^2) - (x_^2 - 2\beta x_1 
x_0 + \beta^2 x_0^2)}{1-\beta^2 }
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

It keeps saying ! Missing { inserted.
 
                   ^
l.227 \end{align}
but I can't see where I went wrong. It has nothing to do with my preamble or other things, I have tried to put something else in there. Everything works fine except for when I write that down. Heeeelp.

Comment: You have a `x_^2` that is causing the error.

Comment: I think \begin{equation} and \end{equation} are missing.

Comment: BTW: You have asked at least 7 questions earlier. Really no one of them is worth your acceptance?

Answer (score 3):

In the place of `?` you probably wanted to have an index:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}



\begin{align}
\begin{split}
{x_0'}^2-{x_1'}^2 & = {(x_0 - \beta x_1)}^2 \gamma^2 - {(x_1 - \beta x_0)}^2 
\gamma^2  \\
& = \frac{ (x_0^2 - 2 \beta x_1 x_0 + \beta^2 x_1^2) - ({x_{?}}^2 - 2\beta x_1 
x_0 + \beta^2 x_0^2)}{1-\beta^2 }
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Please observe also that I have added curly braces around expressions with primes, to explain probable intentions.

Comment: `x_0'^2` is commonly accepted for the square of the derivative.